# Issues with Multiple models and templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am developing an app which consists of multiple models. In my 2nd model in model.py it consist of 2-3 col. of char field but in my template when I am using this **{{ form.billing_add }}** then it doesn't show any text input in browser

my model.py file is as

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user        =models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday    =models.DateField()
    website     =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store       =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    welcomemail =models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
             return self.user

class Customer_check_attributes(models.Model):
    customer    = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    billing_add =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shipping_add    =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    payment_method  =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shipping_method =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reward_points   =models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and  my  form.py file  as

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from customer_reg.models import Customer,Customer_check_attributes

class Registration_Form(ModelForm):
       first_name  = forms.CharField(label=(u'First Name'))
       last_name   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Last Name'))      
       username   = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
       email      = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
       password   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

       class Meta:
              model=Customer

              exclude=('user',)
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have `billing_add`.

Comment: my form also doesn't have birthday and welcome mail but it gets the desired field as I specified in model in browser then why these issues comes with 2nd model

Comment: The `Customer` doesn't know about the `Customer_check_attributes` as the relationship is defined on the `Customer_check_attributes`.  Therefore the form cannot follow all the way through to the `Customer_check_attributes` fields.

Comment: You might be better using a normal `Form`, setting all the fields you need and then using the `cleaned_data` and creating the models yourself once the form `is_valid()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to have a html form which has attributes from multiple models.
So the way would be to create separate form for each model but show it on one page through one view and template and process it in the same.

Here is example

forms

```
#additional user attributes 
class Registration_Form(ModelForm):
     first_name  = forms.CharField(label=(u'First Name'))
     last_name   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Last Name'))      
     username   = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
     email      = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
     password   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
     class Meta:
         model = User

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Customer
         exclude=('user',)

class Customer_check_attributesForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Customer_check_attributes
         exclude=('user',)
```

view:

```
def customer_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         uform = Registration_Form(request.POST)
         cform = CustomerForm(request.POST)
         caform = Customer_check_attributesForm(request.POST)
         if uform.is_valid() :
             ...
             user = uform.save()
         if cform.is_valid() :
             ...
             customer = cform.save()
         if caform.is_valid() :
             ...
             cattr = caform.save()
  else:
      uform = Registration_Form()
      cform = CustomerForm()
      caform = Customer_check_attributesForm()         
  ctx = { 'uform': uform, 'cform':cform, 'caform': caform }
    return render_to_response('add_customer_template.html', ctx,
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Sample add_customer_template.html

```
 <form> 
     {#other rendering logic#}
     {{ uform.as_p }}
     {{ cform.as_p }}
     {{ caform.as_p }}
 </form>
```

Note: this is a guideline code. There is scope for improvement to handle errors and better logic.